# Beacons array is empty in didRangeBeaconsInRegion event in ionic ios app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ibeacon, ionic-native

im using ionic native ibeacon library to detect beacons.I can detect beacons  with android but when I try in ios ,i always see an empty beacon array.
I tried these things ,but still cant see the beacons in ios (device is iphone 6s plus 11.4.1) (bluetooth   service is enabled on device)

- I tried both requestWhenInUseAuthorization and also
  requestAlwaysAuthorization.
- I add NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription  key in info.plist

my code is like this, its working on android device

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { IBeacon } from "@ionic-native/ibeacon";

    @Injectable()
    export class BeaconProvider {
      delegate: any;
      region: any;
      constructor(
        public platform: Platform,
        public events: Events,
        private iBeacon: IBeacon
      ) {
         this.initialise(); 
      }

      initialise(): any {
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          if (this.platform.is("cordova")) {
            this.iBeacon.requestAlwaysAuthorization(); 
           // ALSO try this one too this.iBeacon.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
            this.delegate = this.iBeacon.Delegate();
            this.delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion().subscribe(
              data => {
                this.events.publish("didRangeBeaconsInRegion", data);
               //console.log("didRangebeacons__" + JSON.stringify(data)); // empty beacons array
              },
              error => console.error()
            );
            this.region = this.iBeacon.BeaconRegion("deskBeacon", "e2c56db5-dffb-48d2-b060-d0f5a71096e0");
            this.iBeacon
              .startRangingBeaconsInRegion(this.region)
              .then(
                () => {
                  resolve(true);
                },
                error => {
                  console.error("Failed to begin monitoring: ", error);
                  resolve(false);
                }
              );
          } else {
            resolve(false);
          }
        });

        return promise;
      }
    }
```

**EDIT** 
My location services are on ,and I'm using same uuid in ios or android (ionic,same code).By the way I tried to make a iphone as beacon transmitter by an app in market,other iphone can see it as beacon.
And here is the screenshot of beacon scope app [image]

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check on iOS:

1. Go to settings, location, and check if your app has been granted location permission.
2. Make sure Bluetooth is turned on
3. Try a 3rd party beacon scanner like [Beacon Scope for iOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/beacon-scope/id1315448039?platform=iphone), configure it with your UUID and make sure it can detect your beacon with the same device.

**EDIT: A few more steps**

4. Make sure iOS has Location turned on in Settings (the overall setting, not just for your app)  Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services
5. Since you can detect on Android but not iOS, double check the UUID that you see on Android and make sure it matches exactly what you enter on iOS.
6. If the UUID in the config matches, but it still won't detect, verify that the beacon is actually sending out an iBeacon frame and not AltBeacon or some format iPhone won't see by default.  If you use the [Beacon Scope app for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US), it will tell you the frame type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you answer ,I have checked 1,2 but I cant find my test beacon with iphone (tried 3 iphones and also a ipad ) with couple beacon locater apps in appstore. all iphones are 11.4 and ipad is 11.1.1 .I always set permission as "always" with that apps. Is there something I dont know about the beacon and iphones.

Comment: Added two more troubleshooting steps

Comment: Thanks for your help.I edited my question and upload the screenshot of beacon scope app ,mine is ibeacon too ,but still iphones cant see it .

Comment: OK, to be absolutely clear:  Your iPhones still cannot see this beacon even with a 3rd party scanner app that is configured with this UUID?

Comment: yes , iphones cant see that ibeacon with the apps in the applestore.(tried couple ones). Maybe there is something wrong with beacon for ios .When I searched google ,my uuid seems belong to Apple AirLocate.  And when I searched apple  airlocate, there are some complains about it with apple sample airlocate app.

Comment: I suspect that your hardware beacon is setting the manufacturer code, BLE flags header, or some other low-level field in the bluetooth transmission to something that Apple does not like but Android is tolerant of.  If this is the case, it doesn't rally matter specifically what it is -- the solution will be the same.  You have to get another beacon that doesn't send out a funny packet that iOS hates.